# Is the sentence "Лошадь, которая плохо везёт, нужно бить" grammatically correct?

Tags: синтаксис

**Лошадь, которая плохо везёт, нужно бить.**

Is this good Russian? Is the sentence grammatically correct?

Why yes or why no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the sentence grammatically correct?

Yes, it is.

A couple of examples from the corpus with the same structure:

> - Курицу, которая несет золотые яйца, надо хорошо кормить, а не ждать, когда она начнет околевать. [Александр Бахмуров. Одной рукой — за горло, другой рукой — в карман (2002) // «Дело» (Самара), 11.04.2002]
> - — Машину, которая идет в голове пробега, нужно украсить хотя бы одним лозунгом, — сказал Остап. [Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров. Золотой теленок (1931)]
> - Экстенсивность, которая неизбежно останется присущей земледельческому укладу степи, можно характеризовать не только как таковую; она есть некоторое средство к сохранению в земледельческом населении своеобразного «чувства степи». [П. Н. Савицкий. Континент Евразия (1916-1968)]

> Is this good Russian?

It's an example of a [garden-path sentence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence).

In the first two sentences above, it's obvious from the beginning that the object (*курицу, машину*) is in the accusative, and this is conveyed on the syntactic layer, through the inflectional endings of the nouns.

In the third sentence, and in your example as well, it's not that obvious, up until *нужно*, that it's the accusative. The majority of Russian sentences that begin with a structure similar to *X, которая Y*, use the nominative. When you stumble upon *нужно*, your brain is forced to go back and re-parse the sentence from the beginning.

As garden-path sentences come, this one is not that bad, and it's perfectly grammatical. But if your goal is to write texts that can be easily parsed and understood, you better steer clear of sentences like this. The replacement *если лошадь плохо везёт, её нужно бить* means the same, but is much easier to digest.

Comment: несет золотые яйца - есть дополнение "яйца", а в примере - нет; надо хорошо кормить - тут предикат есть - "хорошо", - в примере нет. Пример выглядел бы так: курицу, которая плохо несёт, нужно кормить. - не выдумывайте, так не пишут. И сама фраза про лошадь для русского человека выглядит, как будто её писал фашист. Неграмотный фашист. И дело не в только в глаголах, а еще в их форме, несовершенного вида, настоящего времени. Фраза откровенно плохая по всем параметрам.

Answer (score 2):

Лошадь, которая плохо везёт, нужно бить.

Well, while grammar seems to be OK, the words you choose sound unnatural. Везти плохо does not collocate. You can't везти хорошо или плохо. Быстро или медленно is correct. Just compare "carry badly"(Do you speak like this in English? Does it make sense? Do you carry anything badly?). Бить is not the correct word. Погонять лошадь — to speed one's horse.
The following sentence is better.

Лошадь, которая идет медленно, нужно погонять.

Comment: Лошадь, идущую  - возможно, но лошадь, которая идет - криво, потому что лошадь - это не подлежащее, а дополнение. Основную фразу помещают в начало: нужно погонять лошадь, которая идет медленно.

Comment: В русском более свободный порядок слов, чем в английском, вам не кажется?

Comment: Если бы было неодушевлённое что-то, то возможно, а тут получается, что лошадь тяготеет к тому, чтобы быть подлежащим, лошадь плохо везёт - подлежащее, а потом кусок, который внезапно делает её дополнением. То тут или: если лошадь идет медленно, её нужно погонять, - или как я писал выше, чтобы не дробить фразу. Ну или такое возможно, в какой-то разговорной фразе, когда было до этого перечисление. Или хотя бы союз воткнуть: а лошадь, которая...

Comment: И, кстати, вы поменяли последний глагол, на глагол с приставкой, а до этого был без, это тоже влияет. Там еще момент, что глаголы попадают в один временной промежуток - идёт и гнать, а идёт и погнать - уже есть небольшой временной зазор между.

Answer (score -2):

Нет, не грамотно, в основном потому что оправдано беспричинное насилие.

Вот примеры пословиц про лошадей и битьё/заботу:

> Добрую лошадь одной рукой бей, другою слезы вытирай. (if *havest to be
> tough to the kindly horse, try to art caring atleast)
>
> Лошади чужие, хомут не свой — погоняй, не стой. (horses - mean if you
> use, the stuff that is not yours, don't be care about it! No ofc -
> take it care also, if not yours - too)
>
> Конь не пахарь, не кузнец, не плотник, а первый на селе работник.
> (a horse is not a plower, not a smith, not a carpenters, but the prime worker in a hamlet)

> На кнуте далеко не уедешь. ( *canst not to go far, if with a whip)

*thou form

Далее, касательно самой фразы, её частей:

Лошадь, которая плохо(?)... - так не говорят. Вообще глагол везёт с наречием - очень сомнительно, потому что "везёт телегу / везёт к / везёт на". Попробуйте согласовать take+bad или drive+bad - это как?

Далее "нужно бить" - не употребляется без указание кого бить или почему бить. В разговорной форме, можно употребить, в частном обращении, но как фраза "нужно бить" - не самодостаточно.

Хотя, это бы даже прокатило, если лошадь была неодушевленным существительным: *ботинок, которых плохо шнуруется, нужно* ... а тут все равно лучше глагол в совершенной форме... *нужно выбросить*.

С другой стороны *лошадь* - одушевленное, и тяготеет к тому, чтобы быть подлежащим, однако, когда дело доходит до конца фразы, где идет обращение к собеседнику, а не к лошади, *лошадь* превращается в дополнение, и от этого фраза звучит плохо.

Если бы это был ботинок, то априори понятно, что к ботинку обращаться не будут и все "ботинок шнуруется" - звучат двояко, но при этом нет обманчивого ощущения, что ботинок - главный герой этой истории.
Возможные фразы:

*Если лошадь медленно везёт телегу, её нужно лучше кормить.*

*Лошадь, везущую телегу вяло, нужно кормить лучше.* - кривовато, но сойдёт.

*Нужно кормить овсом ту лошадь, которая тебя везёт.*

*Нужно кормить овсом лошадь, чтобы та везла всадника доброй рысью.*

Везёт без указания того, что или кого именно везёт становится глаголом "везёт"~*везение* - luck/to get luck, а не to carry.

То есть получается что-то вроде: *той лошади, которую бьют, не везёт с хозяином.*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147981/discussion-on-answer-by--is-the-sentence-----); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I've deleted your harangue from the answer. The answer section is to answer the questions, please don't use it to engage in unrelated discussions. General banter, orations, invectives and complaints about moral depravity of the newer generations belong in the chat. Thank you.